# import class of libs in the Android Studio project is locked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, libs

I copied the `commons-io-2.6.jr` into libs folder, and I've decompressed it. But the icon shows classes were locked. The `FileUtils` class can not be used. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is no the way you use the libraries in Java

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decompress the jar file to use it.
Instead of using the jar, you can import the commons-io library through Gradle.
Add this line in your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    // other libs...
}
```

If you really want to use the jar file, you can import your `libs` folder through Gradle as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700183/9783898).