# Why does the Facebook Android SDK downloaded and included via jar show up as an unresolved reference in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

I was [unable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52200705/1390035) to include the Facebook Android SDK in the normal way so I downloaded a jar and added it to Android Studio.  For some strange reason I get an error `Unresolved reference: FacebookSdk` even though I can see the class in the Project view:

[image]

If I am doing the wrong thing can somebody please give a lucid explanation of how to **download** and use the Facebook SDK in Android Studio 3.

### Edit

I need to use the Facebook SDK in my app and I need to download it and add it 'offline'.

Comment: I think it'll still compile. I have an app with the Samsung SDK loaded as a JAR, and the editor very rarely sees the classes available in that JAR, but the app compiles and runs just fine. I think it's a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: @TheWanderer  Thanks but no. The build fails. It seems that the Facebook SDK can't be added as a jar.

Comment: You did add it as a Gradle dependency right? You still need to manually specify JARs as dependencies.

Comment: @TheWanderer No - how exactly do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20700053/5496177

Comment: Whoops that won't help sorry. I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: @TheWanderer - no problem and yes, it was added there when I added the module so I have `implementation files('libs/facebook-android-sdk-4.4.0-sources.jar')`

Comment: Any reason you have your target and build APIs on 26? It seems Facebook is using 27, so you may want to match that.

Comment: @TheWanderer Yeah, I tried that but couldn't move to API 27.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52200705/1390035  Not a good day for me development wise :-(  If you could answer that question it'd be great.

Comment: I read that question, and that's how I know you're using 26. Update to 27, change any 26 dependencies to. 27 (latest should be 27.1.1) and try compiling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179563/discussion-between-dave-chambers-and-thewanderer).

Answer (score 0):

this is the `sources` package (as it's filename may hint for), which is for reference only. you should possibly add a dependency to the `build.gradle` instead; it's from the `mavenCentral()` repository, you can also find the artifacts [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk) ...and a whole lot of other Facebook SDKs [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android).

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0"
}
```

and also move those `sources` outside of the `libs` directory

(they still can be linked together with the fetched library).

Comment: Thanks.  I will check this out shortly