# Gradle for Java 11 with Modules

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, java-module, java-11

I'm trying to run a sample JavaFX app on Mac OS.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11"
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11"
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11"
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        println "CLASSPATH IS $classpath.asPath"
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.graphics'
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

**Java class**

```
package com.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        Scene scene = new Scene(l, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

I use Gradle 4.10.2

Executing task 'gradle compileJava' I'm getting this error:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
CLASSPATH IS /Users/dragos.pruteanu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/11/58d961774262ec972bf304e16c154a8e18c2050b/javafx-controls-11.jar:/Users/dragos.pruteanu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/a736dd079047ec0b72b8c4970842a5c5e0c19f2f/javafx-graphics-11.jar:/Users/dragos.pruteanu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-base/11/9fcd3e8e3227ec97bf503f7991fad1f3b14d005/javafx-base-11.jar
error: module not found: javafx.graphics
1 error
```

What is wrong? For some reason the JavaFX libraries are not loaded correctly. Could be the error from MacOS or OpenJFX?

Comment: Since you're using Gradle, you need to take a look at the [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) article for Gradle specifically. Some special things must be done when adding the JavaFX modules in the `dependencies`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it would fail for you is mostly that the *automatic module* name derived out of the jar that you've used would ***not be*** *`javafx.graphics`*. Trying to get the details using the command line, I could observe the following:

> ```
> jar --file=.../org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/javafx-graphics-11.jar --describe-module
> No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.
>
> javafx.graphicsEmpty@11 automatic
> requires java.base mandated
> ```

and since the module name resolved is not same as what you've specified in the command line `--add-modules javafx.graphics`, hence you're facing the stated error.

---

Additionally, one of the notes [from Run HelloWorld using JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) reads:

> there is no need to add `javafx.graphics` module, since it is
>   *transitively* required by the `javafx.controls` module

---

***Edit from comments***:- Steps defined at [Run HelloWorld using Gradle](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) with JavaFX would be a better place to look for appropriate steps to build with gradle.

As it states(edits mine), one needs to specify the platform in dependencies for e.g.

```
compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:$platform"
```

> ... classifiers are not taken into account when resolving transitive
>   dependencies in Gradle. Therefore, we need to specify ...
>   modules with platform as classifier

and for which you might need the build script used in the sample as well to specify the platform/OS as a classifier.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'

ext.platform = osdetector.os == 'osx' ? 'mac' : osdetector.os == 'windows' ? 'win' : osdetector.os
```

Comment: Thank you. But now if I remove the javafx.graphics I got : error: module not found: javafx.controls. Probably it has the same issue, with automatic module. How may I get my code compiled ? Won't this automatic modules bring a mess in javafx ? And one question about the HelloWorld article: why do they use OS specific jars ? Is really a distinct distribution for each OS ?

Comment: You may want to mention what's said in [Run HelloWorld using Gradle](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle). One must include the platform classifier when declaring the JavaFX dependencies in Gradle. This also unfortunately means transitive dependencies aren't resolved (though that doesn't affect the `--add-modules` command).

Comment: @dprutean There's OS specific distributions because the native code is unique to each OS.

Comment: @Slaw Ya, ofcourse the link from Gradle would be good to share. I just wanted to point out the dependency clause, in general, to make the OP aware of the correct usage of `--add-modules` command.

Comment: Thank you for help. The sample from HelloWorld article works fine. Now I have one more question: if I have few jars stored in a lib folder, which is the correct way to include them ? I tried using this: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
but it does not work.

Comment: @dprutean I'm not very good at gradle though, but the way [you've specified the *libs* folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file) looks fine to me. Maybe if it doesn't work you can open another SO thread *with the details* and not extend this one.

Comment: I created a separate thread for the last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164973/gradle-migration-to-java-11