# Issue while importing CSVParser in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, corda

I was trying to read a csv file in kotlin using intellij as IDE. I have added dependencies(commons-csv-1.6-bin.zip,link-https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi) and imported the CSVParser. on reading the file am geting an error like this

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser

Comment: How did you add the dependency, and how are you running your application?

Comment: This does not look like a Kotlin problem, but an issue with Gradle, that you seem to be using. You should provide your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the unpacked jar file from `commons-csv-1.6-bin.zip\commons-csv-1.6\commons-csv-1.6.jar` into the [Module Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

If using Gradle, add the library via `build.gradle` [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956456/104891).