# Spring Boot, Gradle and non-Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gradle

Java 8, Spring Boot 1.5.8 and Gradle 4.6 here.

I'm building a Spring Boot app and use the built-in Gradle tasks to produce a self-contained, executable "fat" jar for it. Another team has generated a dependency JAR that I need to incorporate into my project.

In a few months we will have a binary repository set up that they will publish new versions of their library to, and that I will resolve/pull from. But for right now, I'm stuck with the somewhat draconian distribution model where they email me a version and I need to figure out how to get it working with Gradle to get it on the classpath.

So...

My project lives on my machine at `/home/myuser/workspace/my-spring-boot-app`. They have emailed me the first version of their library, say, `some-lib-0.1.0.jar` and I have downloaded it to, say, `/home/myuser/some-lib-0.1.0.jar`).

Another complicating (and important!) factor is that this JAR has no `pom.xml` file with it (yet). They simply included, in their email, a list of all its dependencies which I have already included in my app's `build.gradle` file. So I don't *think* this JAR's dependencies will be a problem, but wanted you all to be aware that there is no `pom.xml` for it, so not sure if that means I need to write my own, etc...

I'm *imagining* that the simplest solution here is to install/import the library into my local Maven/Gradle repository (wherever `mavenLocal()` resolves from)? And that once its imported/installed there, I can just add `mavenLocal()` to my list of `repositories { ... }` and add it as a `compile` dependency, right?

If so, how do I accomplish the first part (getting it into `mavenLocal()` without a POM)? And if not, what *is* the simplest solution here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file    ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the Maven goal `install:install-file` (i.e. `mvn install:install-file` on the command line)

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

and you set `generatePom` to true. So something like

```
mvn install:install-file -DgeneratePom=true -DartifactId=somelib -DgroupId=com.somecompany -Dversion=0.1.0
```