# How do I access (in gradle) an artifactory jar dependency that is not in a Maven or Ivy repo directory structure?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Given an artifactory repo with the url:

```
http://myrepo.myworld.com/my-stuff
```

that contains a jar immediately at the root of the repo:

```
http://myrepo.myworld.com/my-stuff/doofus-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

no metadata, no pom, no other files except for other versions of the jar, how do I write the `repositories` settings and the `dependencies` settings so that the jar is included in the build?

Notes:

1. This solution needs to be something that will build cleanly from a
   gradle command-line after the download of the git repo. It has to
   work in our CI/CD system.
2. I know that I can download the jar, add it to my git repo, and add a
   `flatDir` config to my gradle `repositories`. I do not want to do
   this. I don't want to add a large binary file to my git repo.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it? Would be nice to know how you did it. Facing the same issue!

Comment: I did not. I eventually added it to my git repo (YUK!) and referenced it via flatdir. We also tried to convince the owner of the code to put it in a more standard location. No dice. Eventually we found a way not to use that JAR at all.

Answer (score 3):

I can't test it right now, but you should be able to utilize the functionality for custom Ivy repositories in your setup:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url 'http://myrepo.myworld.com/my-stuff'
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
        patternLayout {
            artifact "[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

The `metadataSources` closure tells Gradle to just watch for artifacts and to not expect any kind of metadata (like a `.pom` or a `.ivy`). The `patternLayout` closure describes how the artifact path should be formed. This might be dependent on how you define the dependency in your `dependencies` block later on. The supported placeholders are:

- `organization`
- `module`
- `revision`
- `artifact`
- `classifier`
- `extension`

Comment: I actually tried exactly that just before submitting this question and it didn't work.

Comment: Gradle should tell you the URLs it requested to resolve your dependencies. Could you post your `build.gradle` and the Gradle output?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to drag the jar file into your project from where its located. For example, if you drag it into your workspace it will show in your project folder. From there you can simply hit right click the jar file and select build path. This will include it in the build and set the path.

Comment: Should add it in the reference libraries

Comment: Has to be IDE independent. I need to build it from a command-line in my CI/CD system.

Comment: ... or are you suggesting that I download the jar and include it in my git repo? (yuk)

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file

Comment: What are your repositories?

Comment: RE repositories: `http://myrepo.myworld.com/my-stuff`, like I said. :) They're behind a company firewall, so what does it matter what the real URL is?

Comment: RE look here: The jar is remote, in a company artifactory repo, not local. Yes, I could make it local by downloading the jar and adding it to the git repo, but I specifically do not wish to do that. I would like to access the jar, *in situ*, from artifactory, without adding a large binary file to my git repo.

Comment: Thanks, sincerely, for the attempt. Given my original problem statement (without the clarifying notes) your solution would actually be pretty good. It's just not what I'm looking/hoping for.