# NoClassDefFoundError with local dependencies when build

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, bukkit

I am developing a Minecraft plugin with Spigot, so far no problem.

I have added several dependencies so an dependencies that refers to a . jar `pixearth-core-1.0` located at the root of the project in a folder `libs`. When I develop, I have access to the classes in the `pixearth-core-1.0` library.

When I compile the project there is no problem, however when I run the plugin on the server, I have the following error:

```
[01:58:17 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling Idle v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pixearth/idleplugin/database/DatabaseManager
        at pixearth.idle.Main.onEnable(Main.java:26) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:339) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:403) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:426) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:340) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R1.MinecraftServer.m(MinecraftServer.java:562) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13R1.MinecraftServer.g(MinecraftServer.java:524) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:423) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:288) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:686) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-fe3ab0d-162bda9]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pixearth.idleplugin.database.DatabaseManager
```

The class `pixearth/idleplugin/database/Databasemanager` is located in the `pixearth-core-1.0` library.

Only the `pixearth-core-1.0` library is not exported during compilation but `spigot-api` and `SQLiteQueryBuilder` are exported.

I’m not sure why, do you have any idea how to fix the problem?

My `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

group = pluginGroup
version = pluginVersion

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'spigotmc-repo'
        url = 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'sonatype'
        url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io/"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.13-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.alexfu:SQLiteQueryBuilder:0.1.1'
    compile files('libs\pixearth-core-1.0.jar')
}

import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: version]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your gradle indicates that you are packaging the dependencies into your jar, so what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file

Comment: @Frontear I want to export the `pixearth-core-1.0' library in my project ... as shown in my post ...

Comment: Using any IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is calling on the library during runtime but it is not found. It needs to either be loaded by spigot as a plugin on its own, or included in your jar. There is a Gradle plugin to help you with this called Shadow. You can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). Here is the [user guide](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) but to summarize, add that to your plugins in buildscript and use task `shadowJar`. Anything with runtime classpath will be included inside your final jar.

It is also recommended to use `implementation` instead of `compile`. It still works in some Gradle versions for compatibility issues but it is deprecated and has been removed from Gradle 7. [More information on Gradle docs site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal.)