# Extent report is not working in Cucumber 4.7.1

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, extentreports

When I tried with Cucumber latest version 4.7.1 *i.e.,'io.cucumber'*,
with Extent report 3.0 the report is not generated. I have tried with different versions in extent report but still the output is generated properly.

I have tried with different combo versions between Cucumber and Extent Report but still no output. Someone could shed the light over here to bring up the output.

**Code:**

```
/**
 * @Author: PriyadarsiniMuthuvel
 * @Created date: 19-08-2019
 * @Project Description: CucumberGradleProject
 **/


import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import managers.FileReaderManager;

import java.io.File;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/SmokeSuite",
        glue= {"stepDef"},
      //  plugin = { "pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports"},
 //  plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"},
    // plugin = { "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"},
      plugin = { "com.aventstack.extentreportscucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"},
        monochrome = true
)
public class testrunner {

    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {

        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getReportConfigPath()));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Machine", System.getProperty ("os.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Java Version", System.getProperty ("java.version"));
    }
}
```

**Console:**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter.getCurrentScenario(Reporter.java:166)
>     at
>   com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter.assignAuthor(Reporter.java:158)
>     at stepDef.Hooks.BeforeSteps(Hooks.java:39)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)  at
>   cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)     at
>   cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)  at
>   cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:65)
>     at
>   cucumber.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:16)
>     at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)   at
>   cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)    at
>   cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:42)    at
>   cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)  at
>   io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:146)
>     at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
>     at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:142)    at
>   io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:65)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:172)    at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   gherkin.formatter.Reporter    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 52 more

Comment: The below dependencies used for the extent reports for io.cucumber.4.7.1:               // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter
    compile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports-cucumber4-adapter', version: '1.0.7'
   // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports
    compile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '3.0.2'

Comment: Priya, what is your cucumber version and Gherkin version that you used/mentioned in **pom.xml**.

Comment: Cucumber 4.7.1. I have separately tried with extent adapter and extent report. But its not workout for me.

Comment: Remove the AfterClass method in runner if you are using the extent adapter.

Comment: Hi @Grasshopper, Thanks for the info. I have tried with the help of below links,http://grasshopper.tech/824/. In that article you have mentioned to add the system path in the pom.xml. i.e., <dependency>
   <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
   <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.8</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>D:/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

Comment: how can I implement the same thing in the gradle.                       
     I has been used like that,                                                                                           // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter
    compile group: 'C:/Users/MSTSYS0/Desktop/CucumberGradleProject/src/test/resources/config/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter.jar', name: 'extentreports-cucumber4-adapter', version: '1.0.8'
Kindly help me in this regards.@Grasshopper

Comment: @PriyadarsiniMuthuvel Refer to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file.

Comment: @PriyadarsiniMuthuvel To obtain the similar thing (system path) in Gradle. Try with adding the dependencies as follows: **dependencies {
    compile files("mention the path of your file")
}**
Keep the path as relative/dynamic rather than absolute.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan. I have used the same thing but its not work out.   testCompile(files("C:/Users/MSTSYS0/Desktop/CucumberGradleProject/src/test/resources/config/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter.jar"))

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan Thanks much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Extent report is not supported in Cucumber **4.7.1v**. Due to that,we have to work with **Extent Report Cucumber Adapter**.

In Gradle add the following things Cucumber 4.7.1, Extent Report Cucumber Adapter 1.0.7

[Gradle path for Cucumber 4.7.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter/1.0.7)

```
compile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports-cucumber4-adapter', version: '1.0.7'
```

In addition to that, manually download the jar and add it to build.gradle as below.

```
 compile files("src/test/resources/config/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter.jar")
```

(We have to include both the versions 1.0.7 & 1.0.8 to make it work)