# Is there a way for Gradle to resolve dependencies using curl command?

Tags: java, curl, gradle

I have loaded several jar files onto a host using curl command line. Now I would like to resolve the dependencies under Gradle'e dependencies block.

I have tried:

```
maven {
  url "xxxxxx"
  artifact() 
}
```

and

```
flatDir { 
      dirs 'http://....' 
}
```

on [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)

and use the relative path under compile "relativePath" but no luck.

Does anyone have tried this before?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file) – the question here does not really have anything to do with `curl` (it doesn't matter how the file was put onto the host. Could as well have been copied with a USB drive)

Comment: @knittl Are you saying I should do something like:
flatDir {
    dirs 'http://....'
} then use a relative path under the url to resolve the dependency?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should specify the relative path on your PC where you downloaded the file. You wrote "I have loaded several jar files onto a host using curl command line" – which I read as: the files have already been downloaded and are available as files locally

Comment: @knittl Sorry about my expression. I mean I want to use curl to get dependencies on the fly instead of loading the jar from local host.