# Use local jar as a dependency in my Gradle Java project

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a local jar file named `mylib.jar`. I want to used it as a dependency in my Gradle Java project.

This is what I tried:

I created a `libs/` folder under project root. I put the jar file under `libs/` folder.

```
MyProject
 ->libs/mylib.jar
 ->build.gradle
 ->src/...
```

In my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

group 'com.my.app'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
 }

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    api files('libs/mylib.jar')
}
```

But I can't access the public classes defined in `mylib.jar` in my project code. Why?

**===== More information =====**

The content of my jar:

```
mylib.jar
    > com.my.jar.package
      >ClassFromJar.class
```

Here is how I use the jar:

```
// Compilation error: Cannot resolve symobl 'ClassFromJar'
import com.my.jar.package.ClassFromJar;

public class MyEntryPoint {
    // Compilation error: Cannot resolve symbol 'ClassFromJar'
    ClassFromJar instance = new ClassFromJar();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say *"can't access the public classes"*? Does the compilation via Gradle fail? Do you use an IDE?

Comment: I mean those public classes declared in jar can't be resolved by compiler.

Comment: But how do you compile them? How do you use Gradle?

Comment: Your setup works for me. There must be something bad in your local setup that is not mentioned in your question. Is the JAR file ok? What exact Gradle command fails with which error? How does your “project code” look? Can you update your question with a [mcve] that shows the error?

Comment: At compile time, I get `Can not find symbol` error which complains the class from Jar can't be resolved. The jar is fine because I can see the content of the jar , it contains the class file of the class I am using.

Comment: I updated my question with more information.

Comment: Regarding the content of your `jar` file: Is the package part a single folder or multiple folders? Also, could you please add the output of running `gradle build` to your question?

Comment: @Leem.fin What IDE are you using? Does your IDE's compiler fail to resolve them or does Gradle's command-line compiler fail to resolve them? Those are two VERY different things and you haven't answered that yet.

Comment: @MichaelZiluck I am using IntellJ Community edition.  I will check what you are asking tonight and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

[Similar answers suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)

1. Local dir

> Add next to your module gradle (Not the app gradle file):
>
> ```
> repositories {
>    flatDir {
>        dirs 'libs'
>    }
> }
> ```

2. Relative path:

> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation files('libs/mylib.jar')
> }
> ```

3. Use `compile fileTree`:

> ```
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'mylib.jar')
> ```

Comment: I am not in Android project. I have only one gradle file in my Gradle project, that's `myProject/build.gradle`, so, do I miss something if you say "Add next to your module gradle (Not the app gradle file)" ?

Comment: And I actually have the `flatDir` thing in my build.gradle.

Comment: @leem.fin see https://riptutorial.com/gradle/example/8349/add-a-local-jar-file-dependency

Comment: Thanks but problem is I have followed all those guidelines, but my project just can't resolve the public class from jar. It is not that I'm not following it.

Comment: @leem.fin can you add class(or main parts) and how you try to use it?

Comment: I updated my question with how I try to use the jar.

Comment: @leem.fin maybe it's something as file/folder permission or case sensitive issue or you need to run clean or missing other dependency jar?

Answer (score 2):

A `flatDir` repository is only required for `*.aar`(which is an Android specific library format, completely irrelevant to the given context). `implementation` and `api` affect the visibility, but these are also Android DSL specific). In a common Java module, it can be referenced alike this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ["*.jar"], dir: "libs")
}
```

And make sure to drop the `*.jar` into the correct one `libs` directory, inside the module.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should use in dependency declaration `compile  name: 'mylib'` in this case `flatDir` will search for mylib.jar.

You could try following build.gradle (it works in my project):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'java-library'

group 'dependency'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile  name: 'mylib'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:

1 - compiler must have access to lib directory and jar 
example:

```
javac -cp .;lib\* *.java
```

2 - ALSO import must be mentioned in java file 
example in your java add

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
```