# Add batik as dependency to Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, batik

Before I'll start - I've looked at the following links and none of them worked for me (my assumption is that I'm doing something wrong):

- https://appmediation.com/how-to-add-local-libraries-to-gradle/
- [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)
- [Use local jar as a dependency in my Gradle Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034975/use-local-jar-as-a-dependency-in-my-gradle-java-project)
- [How do you add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle.kt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166069/how-do-you-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-kt-file)
- [Gradle: how do I include a local jar from a dependent java project in an Android build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360737/gradle-how-do-i-include-a-local-jar-from-a-dependent-java-project-in-an-android)

I'm trying to add Batik to my existing Gradle project, from what I could tell this library is not published over Maven repository.

My project structure is as follow:

```
- root
  - libs
    - batik-1.12
  - src
    - main
      - java
      - resources
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
```

My build.gradle file looks as follow:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I copied the example page of Batik from this link: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html

However, this code cannot be compiled as it does not recognize Batik's source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this list. I guess you will find your dependency: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.xmlgraphics%20batik