# org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple can not be found

Tags: java, android, json, intellij-idea

I have created an Android project and added an external JAR on IntelliJ.
I have already installed "json-simple-1.1.jar" to use package org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple. I did a library setting to use that from the project structure menu. 
But when I run the program, error message says, 
"error: package org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple does not exist
import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.JSONArray;". 
(Not only JSONArray, but the other JSON such as JSONObject)

It worked when I used that outside of the Android project.
Are there any special settings for the Android project?

So far, I stored the jar file under the project folder by making "lib" folder additionally.

Comment: Is that a Gradle based project? Can you share the link to the jar file you are using and provide the source code that is referencing the classes from this jar?

Comment: Yes, it is a Gradle based project. In terms of jar file, I did not install anything from outside. I'm just using the library that IntelliJ has. According to that lib folder, it seems I am using jose4j-0.6.0.jar.

Comment: This library is a different JSON implementation, it has this package: `org.json.simple`. But your code is using completely different JSON: `org.jose4j.json`. You either need to find the correct library or change your code. Also in the Gradle based projects all the dependencies must be defined in the `build.gradle` file, all the changes you make to the project structure will be discarded on reimport. If you need to import a local jar with Gradle, see this question and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but when I made a simple java program without android such as client-server simple program, org.jose4j.json worked normally. So I thought my setting for the android project was wrong. Are there any reasons why it worked at a simple java program and it does not work at the android project?

Comment: It's likely you are using different jars or different code. If you share your projects, I'll tell you what exactly the problem is.

Comment: yea. how can I share my project? there are may programs. Do I store the file on like Github?

Comment: Yes, you can use GitHub, or just zip the folders and use any file sharing service (Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc).

Comment: If you can not access the link, please let me know. I will use google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/build.gradle` `dependencies` section add the following:

```
compile group: 'org.bitbucket.b_c', name: 'jose4j', version: '0.7.0'
```

Reimport/refresh the project in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I added that, but still error happens. I saved the screenshot on the Github.

Comment: It's another issue that is not what your question was about, but the reason is the same: missing libraries. Find the proper dependencies for these libraries and add them in build.gradle. Note that this line has no effect as the libs directory inside the app folder is empty: `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`. If the issue with JSON is solved, feel free to accept the answer as it solves the original problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! In case of finding proper libraries, what is the best way to find?

Comment: Search for the package name at https://mvnrepository.com/ and copy/paste the Gradle dependency line.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it! I did not know this operation in case of using jar file. I just did library setting from project structure.

Comment: As described in the comments above, this approach will not work for Gradle and Maven projects, you must define the dependencies in the build files and IDE will import them.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thank you. If there is a good tutorial for this, would you mind giving me the link? I started the java recently, so there is a bunch of information on the web,  I am not sure which one is the best to refer.

Comment: Learn how to use Gradle, follow the official guides.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @mufugu If you won't accept valid answers, people will not be willing to help you here. It's the least you can do and is not so hard. As I can see from your profile you didn't accept a single answer yet. If there is anything I can improve in this answer, please let me know.