# Adding External JAR's to Grails 4.0 Application

Tags: java, grails

I have tried adding an external .jar file to a grails 4.0 application, and though this has been answered in [3.0 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file), I can't find an answer for 4.0. (Grails 4.0 has changed significantly from 3.0.)

Here's what I've done so far:

- generated a clean project with grails create-app --inplace
- added the following to dependencies section of build.gradle (from root)

```
 runtime fileTree(dir: '/vagrant/libs', include: '*.jar')
```

- Created a /vagrant/libs folder and dropped in .jar file
- From controller class, imported the path and tried constructing object.

```
import ext.*;

...

AnnotationRenderer ar = new AnnotationRenderer()
```

But I always get "unable to resolve class AnnotationRenderer".

Any tips to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To link to an external jar which is not in Maven or any other public repo, in build.gradle repositories section add:

```
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
```

Then in dependencies section add:

```
implementation name: 'myjarfilename'
```

Where my actual filename is myjarfilename.jar (e.g. don't include ".jar" in build.grade),.

Comment: For me it was enough to add this into `build.gradle`: `implementation files('libs/lib.jar')` in Grails 4.0.12 project