# Gradle not picking external JAR

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have few dependencies which I have added from maven and one JAR which I want to use. Now I have added it in the `libs` folder and added the same in my `build.gradle` file by

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

However the `.java` file still has compilation errors.

Next, what I did was to add the library manually in my IntelliJ and that resolves the compilation error but when I do `build gradle` it still says dependency not found.

I don't know how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Project type: Spring Boot
Java: 1.8
IDE: IntelliJ 2020

Comment: This is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file

Comment: Make also sure you have set the correct scope for dependency in Gradle.

Comment: well no, I have already checked that question when I was searching for a fix but i was not able to. 
Perhaps I am missing a configuration not sure.