# Error org.jpl7.JPLException: unsupported blob type passed from Prolog

Tags: java, prolog

Im using java 1.8 with javalin, I'm trying to execute a query stored in prolog-app.pl this is the project tree [there's a main.java inside the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoNDl.png)

I'm running everything on the main as a static test with the following line of code:

```java
Query query = new Query("consult", new Term[] {new Atom("src/prolog-app.pl")});
```

but I'm getting the exception on the title. I tried the absolute path and getting the same result.

I'm using:
Java 1.8,
Swi-Prolog 8.2.4,
JPL 7.4.0,
Gradle

Comment: it may be worth trying the latest SWI-Prolog 8.3.xx version.

Comment: @PauloMoura didn't make the trick :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the jpl from gradle, download the [jpl.jar](https://github-registry-files.githubusercontent.com/19143788/eddb8a80-b0a2-11ea-9392-fa88dd46f1d5?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210731%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210731T231315Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=03497fd2076f17243ddc1880e64dc81ae6bbcf95d5184074957b81e73a599ccd&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=19143788&response-content-disposition=filename%3Dpackages-jpl-7.6.1.jar&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream), and use it locally.

Check this thread to learn how to use local libraries with gradle [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)