# Can't import class from jar file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, jar, importerror

So I am trying to import this class from my jar file. IntelliJ recognizes access to all the folder structures but not the class.
[image]
Says: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Constants'.

Note that I have tried clicking "*Add library 'premiumdue.main.jar' to classpath*" and it still doesn't work.

I have no idea why it won't let me import the class.

Here is a minimal intellij project showing my issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzvv2x1ca2lld26/jar_issues.zip?dl=0

Comment: Did you add this jar to the module dependencies per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency? If it's already added, please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes I have added it doing it that way. I have already tried doing the invalidate and restart but I will try again.

Comment: If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I think I've got a project example. How do I share it? Can I upload the IntelliJ project somewhere?

Comment: Use any file sharing service.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzvv2x1ca2lld26/jar_issues.zip?dl=0
I'm not sure that the jar file will be included in the intellij project (it is on my computer). But I included it in the zipped folder incase it doesn't (and you can add it to the intellij project yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample Gradle project, the dependency jar has to be referenced in `build.gradle` file as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956456/104891).

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('../create_jar.jar')
}
```

Proof:

[image: proof]