# How to compile and run a "unmanaged" Java project with gradle using the existing jars

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have an "unmanaged" Java project in VS Code (i.e. no maven or gradle is used in the project) with all the library jars in a lib folder. The directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── args4j-2.0.15.jar
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar
└── src
    └── com
        └── mycompany
            └── myteam
                └── myproject
                    ├── console
                        ├── File1.java
                        ├── ...
                        └── FileN.java
                    └── utils
                        ├── File1.java
                        └── File2.java
```

VS Code can compile and run the project. Now I would like to run it from the command line using gradle.

How do I set up the `build.gradle` file to compile and run the project using the jars in the lib folder and not trying to download stuff from the internet? (The machine is air-gapped.)

Comment: (A complete hack as I don't know gradle: you can install them in a local maven repo with mvn install:install-file and declare the local maven repo. I had to do it this way for a really old maven project.)

Comment: @dcolazin Thanks. I think I go with the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file.