# How to tell Gradle to use for all Java imports the JAR files given in a lib folder and not to require the implementation line for these JARs?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies

I am just starting out with Gradle and I am converting an unmanaged (Eclipse) Java project into a Gradle command line project.

All library JARs are in a local directory (the machine is air-gapped and has no access to a Maven repo or similar), so I tell Gradle about this in the `build.gradle` file with:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs("lib")
    }
}
```

In this directory I have, e.g. the jar `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` which I use in my Java code with

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
```

However, this does not seem to be enough for Gradle: *Additionally* I need to add to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
}
```

Now Gradle can build my sample project. So far so good.

However in my real project I have many JAR in the lib folder and it seems tedious to look up the implementation spec for each jar file.

For each library used in the Java code is only *one* JAR file in the lib directory available, so is there a way to tell Gradle to just use the JAR file it finds in the lib folder as the implementation? Then I do not need to write out all the (superfluous) `implementation ...` lines.

Thanks for any pointer!

Comment: *Gradle* does know about the JARs **only** because of the `implementation` (or equivalent) lines, it does not scan the source location for what is available there. The *Java compiler* looks for libraries it needs during compilation, but that does not know about the Gradle repositories. Usually, you do not need to list all JARs in the `build.xml` as the libraries list their dependencies in POM files, but these may be missing in your setup.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897638/8681) answer your question?

Comment: @Jorn That got me on the right track: It needs the keyword `implementation` instead of `compile`, but it does _exactly_ what I want! Super Thanks. -- Please, please make this info into an answer _here_ (or let me do it). Please do _not_ vote for closing this question, because the other _question_ (where the helpful answer comes from) is quite different to this question here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897638/65889) from [Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8681/jorn)'s comment, the problem can be solved for Gradle 8 with the following directive in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // Use all libraries provided as jars in the lib folder
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

When using this directive you do not need to provide the `repositories flatDir" directive anymore.

However, make sure in your `lib` folder is only *one* JAR version per library. If the directory contains multiple versions of a library (e.g. `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` and `xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar`), then Gradle doesn't seem to be smart enough to use the newest one by default and you might get (unexpected) compile errors.