# SonarQube Exclude a directory

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to exclude a directory from being analyzed by Sonar. I have the following properties defined in my `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.sources=src/java
sonar.exclusions=src/java/test/****/*.java
```

The directory structure I have is:

```
src/java/dig
src/java/test/dig
```

When I run the sonar-runner I get the following info:

```
 INFO  - Excluded sources:
 INFO  -   src/java/test/**/*.java
 INFO  - Excluded tests:
 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
```

But when I check the result of the analysis all the packages inside the test directory are still there.

I just need to tell Sonar to not analyze the test directory and any packages inside it.

Comment: I found the solution:  sonar.exclusions=test/**/*.java

Comment: But if you want to avoid test analysis you can try using for example **mvn clean package -DskipTests**

Comment: Why are you using 4 *? I think it is ** for folders and * for characters

Comment: The documentation is at: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

Answer (score 203):

Try something like this:

```
sonar.exclusions=src/java/test/**
```

Comment: Assure to use the Ant fileglob pattern for wildcards. Here is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/86915/748524

Comment: Here is command line options definition https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions

Comment: Anyone who sees this, make sure you have `src/test/java` instead of `src/java/test/`.

Comment: How to exclude methods in c#

Comment: Its important to note that this isn't treated as a regular expression and applied across your entire project `sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**` will NOT exclude nested node_modules folders you will need to do `sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**, /some/path/to/nested/node_modules/**` to explicitly exclude them

Comment: The folder structure also matters : for example : **/webapp/**/* will exclude all files under webapp directory. The "**" is for directory and "*" is for file. If you just have **/webapp/* then it won't exclude the folders under webapp folder.

Answer (score 134):

I'm able to exclude multiple directories using the below config (comma separated folder paths):

```
sonar.exclusions=system/**, test/**, application/third_party/**, application/logs/**
```

And while running the sonar runner I got the following in the log:

```
Excluded sources: 
  system/**
  test/**
  application/third_party/**
  application/logs/**
```

Comment: I get the excluded message too, but files are still analyzed.

Comment: in Teamcity parameters I used your tip, but inserting -D before (-Dsonar.exclu...). Works here. :-)

Comment: How to exclude all *.html files from scanning here? Tried this `sonar.exclusions=**/bin/**,*.html` but it still takes html files also in the scanning. Html files are all sub folders in several places and adding in sub folder level here with actual path map will be more work. Is there a way we can exclude all *.specific_file_type from getting scanned?

Comment: It works! you need to make sure that the path and wild char is used correctly

Answer (score 28):

This will work for your case:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/src/java/dig/ ** , **/src/java/test/dig/ **
```

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

Answer (score 24):

If we want to skip the entire folder following can be used:

```
sonar.exclusions=folderName/**/*
```

And if we have only one particular file just give the complete path.

All the folder which needs to be exclude and be appended here.

Comment: What is the difference between that answer and `sonar.exclusions=folderName` and `sonar.exclusions=folderName/**` ? Thanks

Comment: * - Match zero or more characters
    ** - Match zero or more directories
    ? - Match a single character

Answer (score 20):

Another configuration option is adding a maven properties `sonar.exclusions`.  Below is a sample pom file with exclusions of static jquery directory and static pdf viewer directory.

```
<project >
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>my Artifact</artifactId>
<!-- Enviroment variables can be referenced as such: ${env.PATH} -->
<packaging>war</packaging>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>

    <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.7</jackson.version>
    <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>

    <!--Exclude the files Here-->
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/static/jquery_ui/*,src/main/webapp/static/pdf-viewer/*,src/main/webapp/static/pdf-viewer/**,src/main/webapp/static/pdf-viewer/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're an Azure DevOps user looking for both where and how to exclude files and folders, here ya go:

1. Edit your pipeline
2. Make sure you have the "Prepare analysis on SonarQube" task added. You'll need to look elsewhere if you need help configuring this. *Suggestion: Use the UI pipeline editor vs the yaml editor if you are missing the manage link. At present, there is no way to convert to UI from yaml. Just recreate the pipeline. If using git, you can delete the yaml from the root of your repo.*
3. Under the 'Advanced' section of the "Prepare analysis on SonarQube" task, you can add exclusions. See advice given by others for specific exclusion formats.

Example:

```
# Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner, 
# Put one key=value per line, example:
# sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
sonar.exclusions=MyProjectName/MyWebContentFolder/**
```

Note: If you're not sure on the path, you can go into sonarqube, view your project, look at all or new 'Code Smells' and the path you need is listed above each grouping of issues. You can grab the full path to a file or use wilds like these examples:

- MyProjectName/MyCodeFile.cs
- MyProjectName/**

If you don't have the 'Run Code Analysis' task added, do that and place it somewhere after the 'Build solution **/*.sln'  task.

Save and Queue and then check out your sonarqube server to see if the exclusions worked.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to go to the server URL after starting the server(localhost:8080) then login as admin,Go to settings>Exclusions> Source File Exclusions- Add your packages here.
Restart the server.

Answer (score 4):

what version of sonar are you using?
There is one option called "**sonar.skippedModules=yourmodulename**".

This will skip the whole module. So be aware of it.

Comment: WARN  - 'sonar.skippedModules' property is deprecated since version 4.3 and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same with `build.gradle`

```
sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/src/java/test/**/*.java"
  }
}
```

And if you want to exclude more files/directories then:

```
sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/src/java/test/**/*.java, **/src/java/main/**/*.java"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I typed case sensitive and used "" and it worked. Analyze time decreased to 3 minutes from 10.

```
# Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner, 
# Put one key=value per line, example:
sonar.exclusions=**\Scripts\**\*,**\Content\**\*
```

Answer (score 3):

**Add comma separated folder paths** `sonar.exclusions=**/abc/**,**/def/**`

This worked in an angular project

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that once you excluded the files from Sonar, do the same for Jacoco plugin:

```
<configuration>
<excludes>     
<exclude>com/acme/model/persistence/entity/TransactionEntity*</exclude>
<exclude>com/acme/model/persistence/ModelConstants.class</exclude>
</excludes>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your sonar-project.properties file

ex: sonar.exclusions=src/*.java
be careful if you want to exclude a folder and inside the folder there is a file you must first exclude the files or add the files one by one 
for example imagine there is a folder like below:

`src/app.java
src/controllers/home.java
src/services/test.java`

you have to do this:
`sonar.exclusions=src/app.java,src/controllers/*.java,src/services/*.java`

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can skip library like this

```
project(":libABC") {
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    sonarqube {
        skipProject = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it works in the Sonarqube now

```
-Dsonar.exclusions=Foodzy.Core/wwwroot/font-awesome/**
```

or In Jenkins

```
/d:sonar.exclusions=Foodzy.Core/wwwroot/font-awesome/**
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
sonar.exclusions=src/**/wwwroot/**/*.js,src/**/wwwroot/**/*.css
```

It excludes any .js and .css files under any of the sub directories of a folder "wwwroot" appearing as one of the sub directories of the "src" folder (project root).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be substantially different from other answers.  It uses double star wildcards just like many other answers.  It doesn't match what the question was trying to exclude.