# How to exclude directory from SonarQube analysis?

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am running Spring Boot project which I want to analyze with SonarQube.

in a `~/static/~` folder I have libs (boostrap and JS) that I want to exclude from analyze.

I have tried both ways:

1. Setting up `project-sonar.properties` file with `sonar.exclusions=**/static/**/*`
2. Going from Sonar project local web to Coverage Exlusions also setting `sonar.exclusions=**/static/**/*`

But none of the ways seem to be working for me.

I would appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try one of these:

`sonar.exclusions=**/static/**`

Or
Full path before `static` e.g. :

`sonar.exclusions=/put/your/full/path/static/**`

Comment: Does it matter where sonar-project.properties file is placed?
I mean I have tried to place it almost everywhere.

Comment: Where is it placed ? Place it in the root folder where `settings.gradle` or `README` for example are.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323276/sonarqube-exclude-a-directory) which is more or less the same question posted by you. Hope that would be helpful.