# How to exclude files with spaces in the path in Sonar?

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, ant, sonarqube

I am trying to exclude some auto generated code (Service References) from Sonars static code and unit test coverage analysis. The project is C# .Net and Sonar is running via Jenkins on a Windows server.

Within my sonar-project.properties file I am able to exclude various other files and directories by using the sonar.exclusions property, but this is not working for files that have a space in the path.

```
sonar.exclusions=**/Global.asax.cs, **/MyProject/Service References/*
```

Given the above example the Global.asax.cs files are excluded in all projects within the solution, but the Service References are not.

I have tried enclosing the path in single and double quotes.
I have tried using a backslash to escape the space. 
I have tried putting the path as **/MyProject/Service*/* to take advantage of the wildcard (could be risky) but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps surrounding the value with double quotes will work? Something like `"/MyProject/Service References"`

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same problem. I needed to exclude javascript files in a Project, "My Project", in a folder Scripts. I tried this first:

```
**/Scripts/**/*.js
```

And that worked fine, but I realized it would exclude a "Scripts" folder in other projects too. So I changed it to this:

```
**/My Project/Scripts/**/*.js
```

And it stopped working. My first instinct was that the space in the project name was to blame. So i tried the same things you did:

```
"**/My Project/Scripts/**/*.js"
'**/My Project/Scripts/**/*.js'
**/My\ Project/Scripts/**/*.js
```

but none of it worked.

Then I stumbled upon this forum: [sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Project-exclusions-for-Code-Coverage-not-working-C-td5023058.html](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Project-exclusions-for-Code-Coverage-not-working-C-td5023058.html)

Particularly this line provided the answer: **Modules (.Net projects) are not part of the fully qualified name. You must define exclusions at module (.Net project) level.**

It means that my mistake wasn't having a space in the project name, but including the project name at all! I changed the filter to this:

```
Scripts/**/*.js
```

and voila, the files were correctly excluded. No quotes or escaping necessary.

Of course, this still leaves the problem that a "Scripts" folder in another project wil also be excluded. The information provided here: [docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Excluding+Artifacts+from+the+Analysis](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Excluding+Artifacts+from+the+Analysis)  may prove useful for that.

I use the web interface, and not the configuration file directly, but this would also suggest that if you have multiple filters, that the comma-separated list should not contain spaces (other than the ones actually in the path) because they are interpreted quite literally.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I tried sonar.exclusions=Service References/*.cs as you suggest as well as sonar.skippedModules=Service References/*.cs as is alluded to in the context of your response, but neither resulted in the exclusion of the service references in the analysis. Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: That's too bad. What type of files do you wish to exclude in the Service References folder? My solution will only exclude .cs files in the Service References folder. If you want to exclude all files you would use sonar.exclusions=Service References/**

Comment: There are folders that contain .cs files as well as .wsdl and other types. I tried sonar.exclusions=Service References/**, sonar.exclusions=Service References/*/**, sonar.skippedModules=Service References/**, and sonar.skippedModules=Service References/*/**. No dice.

Comment: Try sonar.exclusions=Service References/**/* which should give you all files in all subfolders, source:http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#NarrowingtheFocus-Patterns

Comment: This may be obvious, but are you re-running the analysis to see the changes? Also, make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces. So don't do this: "sonar.exclusions=**/Global.asax.cs, Service References/**", but do this: "sonar.exclusions=**/Global.asax.cs,Service References/**".

Comment: I edited my answer to more accurately describe the problem I had, and to make it more clear.

Comment: I think the disconnect here could be that I have a solution that contains multiple projects. In my example above I am not including the solution name, but I am including the project name. Perhaps you have just a single project?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. My solution also contains multiple projects. That's why I'm still surprised that the project is not part of the full qualified name. I would have expected the exclusion filter to be matched against the full path, or at least from a solution level, but that's not the case. Perhaps it's a result of Sonar's Java origins?

Comment: I'm using the older sonar-runner-2.0. What are you using for the Sonar Runner - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe?