# SonarQube Exclude a directory with whitespace in the directory name

Tags: tfs

I am trying to exclude some auto generated code from Sonars static code.The folder name I need to exclude is "BusinessLogic Development" .Tried like this 
sonar.exclusions=***BusinessLogic Development*

But it is not working. It works fine for other directory don't have any white space in the name.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this to. You can use the ? wildcard in the name of the folder. ? means any 1 character, so it will resolve the space.

sonar.exclusions='**/Business?Logic?Development/**'

will exclude /Business Logic Development/ and all sub folders. It will also exclude Business_Logic_Development, Business1Logic2Development, etc... anything with a character between those words. So you could accidentally exclude something you don't want to, but if folks have two folders so similarly named in the same project, you probably have other concerns :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below ways:

1. `sonar.exclusions=BusinessLogic Development/**/*`
2. If it has subfolders which without space in the folder name, you can
   try to set it as :`sonar.exclusions=**/subfolder/**/*`  if that not
   work, just try `/subfolder/**/*`

For the patterns please refer to: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns

Reference this thread: [How to exclude files with spaces in the path in Sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731763/how-to-exclude-files-with-spaces-in-the-path-in-sonar)

Also you can try to use a directory without a whitespace.

Comment: @user3634685 Have you resolved the issue ? Any update for this issue?