# Build step 'Publish Performance test result report' changed build result to FAILURE Finished: FAILURE

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Cannot detect file type because of error, and : Failed to copy  Build step 'Publish Performance test result report' changed build result to FAILURE Finished: FAILURE. whenever i run the script always i face this..

Comment: Can you give the context of your question ? what are you doing, what should happen, what you obtain instead , and show full log and stacktrace if any. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into Jenkins [Console Output](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+Console+Output+Plugin) - it should give you the reason for the failure.

Most probably the Performance Plugin fails to find JMeter's .jtl results file in [Jenkins Workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397329/jenkins-project-artifacts-and-workspace), either the .jtl results file is missing or you're pointing the Performance Plugin to the incorrect location.

If you have a Script step to run a JMeter test like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

You should be able to use simply `result.jtl` in the Performance Plugin.

[image]

Check out:

- [Performance Trend Reporting](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html)
- [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)
- and [Running Performance Tests](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html) articles for more details on various aspects of Jenkins Performance Plugin use cases.