# What is a Jenkins Workspace directory?

Tags: c++, jenkins, directory

I'm using R scripts with C++ code under the hood. An error message references a Jenkins Workspace with the file I'd like to debug. The workspace directory appears to be temporary and I'm unable to find this file:

> c:\jenkins\workspace\mxnet\mxnet\src\operator\tensor../elemwise_op_common.h:123: Check failed: assign(&dattr, (*vec)[i])

How should the directory `c:\jenkins\workspace\...` be understood?

Where would I look for the header file `elemwise_op_common.h`?

Answer (score 0):

The file should be in

```
 c:\jenkins\workspace\mxnet\mxnet\src\operator\elemwise_op_common.h
```

The `\../` being for getting one folder up.

The workspace is where Jenkins checks out the sources, and execute its job.
It [differs from a build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39403204/6309).
See more at "[Building a software project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)".

Comment: Is `/jenkins/` a temporary or invisible file? I don't see it under `c:/`.

Comment: @ConnerM. No it is the folder used by the *agent*. In a simple installation, the machine hosting the Jenkins server also acts as an agent. But in your case, if you have a separate machine for that agent, then C:\jenkins would be there.

Comment: @ConnerM. As for the header itself... maybe https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/src/operator/elemwise_op_common.h.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project does not explain what a workspace is.

Comment: @alex True, and it depends if you are using pipelines or not (https://www.selikoff.net/2016/07/10/workspace-jenkins-pipelines/. If not, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins