# Cannot detect file type because of error: Failed to copy - JENKINS - JMETER (Performance plugin)

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, report

I am trying to configure Performance result report in Jenkins. Below is my code for execution:
[image]

**for the Build:**
jmeter -j jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\Users\Aliaksandra_****\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\R.jmx -l C:\Users\Aliaksandra_*****\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\R_result_report.jtl

**For Performance result report:**
C:\Users\Aliaksandra_****\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\R_result_report.jtl

After that I can not end the build because I have this ERROR IN JENKINS:
[image]
Cannot detect file type because of error: Failed to copy

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using [relative paths](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm#GUID-5118AC85-57E4-4027-AC24-FB6E99FADEFF) so the results file will be generated in the Jenkins build [workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397329/jenkins-project-artifacts-and-workspace) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t R.jmx -l R_result_report.jtl
   ```
2. Your Jenkins seems to be running on Linux so I don't think that Windows absolute paths will work so I would suggest to re-consider the way of launching the test and feeding the results to the [performance plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)
3. The correct way of [passing properties to JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) is using capital `J` without space between `J` and the property name:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t ....
   ```

More information: [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)

Comment: No, I do not use Linux, I have Windows. The thing is in cmd command line it works well  but not in Jmeter.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work