# Where does Jenkins store downloaded files?

Tags: jenkins, download, default

I know that Jenkins default home dir is var/lib/jenkins, but under this path, where is the downloads folder where all downloaded files are stored by default?

Comment: "Files", ie, your repository, are downloaded to the job's [workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39403204/598141). You'll have to elaborate what you mean by files, if that's not sufficient.

Comment: Okay, let's imagine that an automated test case using chrome driver and selenium is executed, and it opens a pdf in a new tab and press download button. Locally, that would go to the download's user folder, but where does it go in Jenkins?